# Cant get JSON object

Tags: android, json

I'm tryin to code an android delivery application, i have added google maps api and i can get my location on the map but i'm having some trouble in the function that draws the routes (the path that the shipper must follow) !!

```java
private void drawRoute(final LatLng yourLocation, final Request request) {

    //clear all polyline
    if (polyline != null)
        polyline.remove();

    if (request.getAddress() != null && !request.getAddress().isEmpty()) {
        mService.getGeoCode(request.getAddress()).enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                try {
          //IM GETTING ERROR AT THIS LINE          
JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
```

```java
public interface IGeoCoordinate {

@GET("maps/api/geocode/json")
    Call<String> getGeoCode(@Query("adresse") String adresse);
}
```

I'm getting this "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference" probably my response is null but i dont know how ?

Comment: can you post the JSON you get?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to be defensive in your programming - checking for `null` values, etc.

The easiest and most canonical way to do this in the Java world is to wrap it in a try/catch:

```
try {
  JSONObject jsonObject =new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
} catch(JSONException e) {
  Log.d("MY CLASS NAME", "Unable to parse JSON Object", e.printStackTrace());
}
```

... though there are other architectural patterns - ([MVI](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/mosby3-mvi-1), for example), and languages ([Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/), etc.) that can help you here...